# fill a custom excel template from sql server proc with multiple result sets?

Tags: asp.net, excel, sql-server-2008, ado.net

A stored proc (SQL Server 2008) returns multiple result sets.

An Excel (.xls) file with custom formatting - **not** a generic workbook, **not** a spreadsheet built on the fly - has particular cells on particular 
worksheets where I need to correctly "paste" each appropriate result set 
from the stored proc. The worksheets designated for holding data need to 
receive the data, and then other worksheets in the workbook will display the data 
with a high degree of formatting and with charts.

For example: 
result set 1 needs to be pasted in a worksheet named 'data01'
and beginning at cell B2;

result set 2 needs to be pasted 'data01' 
and beginning at cell K2;

result set 3 needs to be pasted in a worksheet named 'data02' 
and beginning at cell B2...

What are some approaches for tackling this problem 
in a .NET environment? I have not found examples 
or lessons which duplicate this scenario.

**Update:**
Essentially I'm wondering if it's possible to do what 
SpreadsheetGear does with an excel template, without 
having to pay thousands for a third party tool. 
http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/excel.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Zach Hunter's blog,
http://zachhunter.net/

he has a number of posts on how to make user of NPOI.
http://npoi.codeplex.com/

In particular, these two articles were invaluable:
"Use NPOI to populate an Excel template"
http://www.zachhunter.net/2010/05/npoi-excel-template/

"Improved NPOI ExportToExcel Function"
http://www.zachhunter.net/2010/06/improved-npoi-exportdatatabletoexcel-function/

Answer (score 1):

[Importing and Exporting Data by Using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

[Exporting SQL Server Data to Excel (SQL Server Video)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff686858.aspx)

Comment: The Import/Export wizard does not appear to support multiple sql statements.